# change \figurename when using babel

Tags: captions, babel

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}                                             
%\usepackage[latvian]{babel}                                                    
\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{cap}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}` fails once I uncomment the line

`\usepackage[latvian]{babel}`.

The purpose is to override the settings in babel.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `\addto\captionslatvian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{att.}}`.